# Mongo db connect() seg faults in OSX

Tags: c++, macos, mongodb, mongodb-c

I recently moved to mac, I am working in a c++ app that uses MongoDB.

The code worked in Ubuntu but when I rum it on MAC I get segmentation faults when trying
to connect, I do not even get exceptions (which I am catching).

The server is up and running and if I connect it trough pymongo or the mongo shell it works ok and I can read the collections.

I get the seg fault here :

```
conn = new mongo::DBClientConnection();
conn->connect(url,err_msg);
```

It does not matter if url = "localhost" , "localhost:27017", etc... it always seg faults when I call connect and
the object (conn) is instantiated and allocated correctly which I  double checked.

is there any known issues with the latest c++ driver and mac osx mountain lion? Do I perhaps need to sign my
application or run it as root?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd suggest trying their mailing list. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Technical+Support

Comment: Can you post the code that declared (and initialized) `url` and `err_msg`? Do you get any compiler warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Try building [`mongo-cxx-driver` from github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver) with these options:

```
sudo scons --libc++ --c++11=on --cpppath=/opt/local/include --libpath=/opt/local/lib --prefix=/opt/local install
```